# A quick loony riddle

Tags: riddle

Here's a nice simple riddle I thought up while eating lunch (not related!)

> "There's nothing new under the sun", they say..
> ..but my home is, every time I am between you and the sun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You're referring to the "New Moon", which occurs when the moon is between Earth and the sun. Given your comment, you must therefore be "the man in the moon".

Comment: Also, rot13(gur gvgyr vf n cha ba "yhan" = "ybbal")

Comment: @Mithical - yeah, but that was sort confirmation for me, rather than a clue.

Comment: in honesty (or technically), you have identified my home, but not me..

Comment: @Konchog - See edit. But note that it wasn't clear that you were asking "Who am I" as well as "What is my home".